# BULKAPI or Salesforce appears to be HTML Encoding data before inserting into LONG TEXT AREA

Tags: salesforce, dbamp

I am currently working on an effort to migrate data from an older Salesforce org to a brand new Salesforce org. To facilitate the migration, we are using a product called DBAmp that runs on a SQL Server database and provides stored procedures to replicate Salesforce objects in SQL Server database tables and to load data from SQL Server database tables into Salesforce objects. DBAmp uses bulkapi and bulkapi2 to load the data. The one object I have run into an issue with is the Task object and more specifically the Description (Comment) field which is defined as LONG TEXT AREA(32000). It appears something in Salesforce/bulkapi is HTML Encoding the Description data, making it exceed 32000 bytes and causing the record to fail with a STRING_TOO_LONG error.

Here are the steps I am taking:

1. Use DBAmp SF_Replicate stored procedure to pull all the records from the Task object in the source org into a SQL Server table.
2. Run a stored procedure to grab the relavent records and clean up the data prior to loading it into the target org. Data is stored in a new table called Task_Insert.
3. Run the DBAmp SF_TABLELOADER stored procedure with the "bulkapi" option to load the data in Task_Insert into the target Salesforce org Task object.
4. In the target org, monitor the bulkapi load job in the "Monitor Bulk Data Load Jobs" screen.
5. When complete, click the job id to view the requests and results in the job details.

At this point, most of the records were successfully loaded. A smaller subset though failed with STRING_TOO_LONG on the Description field. I verified the actual data is less than 32000 bytes coming from the SQL Server database. When I looked at the bulkapi request in the job details, I can see that the text is plain text and looks right. When I look at the results in the job details, the data is HTML Encoded. It appears that this html encoding is increasing the size of the field quite a bit, mostly converting crlf's to 
, which is why I suspect this HTML Encoding is causing the issue. When I look at the successfully loaded records using a SOQL query, there is no HTML Encoding in the text. It's like something is HTML Encoding prior to inserting the data into the object, yet with the successful records (with much smaller descriptions) it is not encoded after being inserted.

I was actually able to get the records loaded by using the "bulkapi2" option when using the DBAmp SF_TABLELOADER stored procedure. I am suspecting this issue has something to do with bulkapi.

Does anyone know what could be doing the HTMl Encoding or know if there is another issue I am not considering? I am glad I got it to work with bulkapi2, but I would love to know why bulkapi has an issue and not bulkapi2. Thanks!